# Why is the race detector not detecting this race condition?

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, race-condition, goroutine

I am currently learning the Go programming language and I am now experimenting with the [atomic](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/) package.

In this example, I am spawning a number of Goroutines that all need to increment a package level variable. There are several methods to avoid race conditions but for now I want to solve this using the `atomic` package.

When running the following code on my Windows PC (`go run main.go`) the results are not what I expect them to be (I expect the final result to be 1000). The final number is somewhere between 900 and 1000. When running the code in the Go Playground the value is 1000.

Here is the code I am using: https://play.golang.org/p/8gW-AsKGzwq

```
var counter int64
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    num := 1000
    wg.Add(num )
    for i := 0; i < num ; i++ {
        go func() {
            v := atomic.LoadInt64(&counter)
            v++
            atomic.StoreInt64(&counter, v)

            // atomic.AddInt64(&counter, 1)

            // fmt.Println(v)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("final", counter)
}
```

```
go run main.go
final 931

go run main.go
final 960

go run main.go
final 918
```

I would have expected the race detector to give an error, but it doesn't:

```
go run -race main.go
final 1000
```

And it outputs the correct value (1000).

I am using go version `go1.12.7 windows/amd64` (latest version at this moment)

My questions:

- Why is the race detector not giving an error, but am I seeing different values when running the code without the race detector?
- My theory why the Load/Store combination is not working is that the two atomic calls are not atomic as a whole. In this case I should be using the `atomic.AddInt64` method, is that right?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: This is a good example of how atomics don't provide synchronization, they only provide safe concurrent access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing racy in your code, so that's why the race detector detects nothing. Your `counter` variable is always accessed via the [`atomic`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/) package from the launched goroutines and not directly.

The reason why sometimes you get 1000 and sometimes less is due to the number of active threads that run goroutines: [`GOMAXPROCS`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS). On the Go Playground it's 1, so at any time you have one active goroutine (so basically your app is executed sequentially, without any parallelism). And the current goroutine scheduler does not put goroutines to park arbitrarily.

On your local machine you probably have a multicore CPU, and `GOMAXPROCS` defaults to the number of available logical CPUs, so `GOMAXPROCS` is greater than 1, so you have multiple goroutines running *parallel* (truly parallel, not just *concurrent*).

See this fragment:

```
v := atomic.LoadInt64(&counter)
v++
atomic.StoreInt64(&counter, v)
```

You load `counter`'s value and assign it to `v`, you increment `v`, and you store back the value of the incremented `v`. What happens if 2 parallel goroutines do this at the same time? Let's say both load the value `100`. Both increment their local copy: `101`. Both write back `101`, even though it should be at `102`.

Yes, the proper way to increment counters atomically would be to use [`atomic.AddInt64()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#AddInt64) like this:

```
for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
    go func() {
        atomic.AddInt64(&counter, 1)
        wg.Done()
    }()
}
```

This way you'll always get 1000, no matter what `GOMAXPROCS` is.

Comment: but even if GOMAXPROCS is 1, how come 1000 concurrent threads do not cause a race condition? say counter=100, thread1 loads counter into v, increments it, so v=101. then context switch, thread2 loads counter into v, increments it, so v=101, and stores 101 in memory, then context switch back to thread1, and it stores 101 as well

Comment: @mangusta Theoretically you could get less than 1000 with 1 thread too, but the current goroutine scheduler does not put goroutines to park arbitrarily. So the "context switches" you anticipate are not there.

Comment: could you elaborate this a bit: "but the current goroutine scheduler does not put goroutines to park arbitrarily" ? the scheduler does not perform a context switch in the middle of goroutine ?

Comment: The only assumptions you can make are those presented in the language  and memory model specifications. The compiler is free to optimize the order of operations within that model. You have no synchronization providing any "happens before" relationship between the goroutines, so the code and runtime is free to reorder the operations according to the spec, even within a single thread.

Comment: @mangusta I'm not familiar with the exact implementation, but yes, a goroutine is not interrupted only when certain events happen, such as a blocking IO or syscall is encountered, a channel send/receive would block, or [`runtime.Gosched()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Gosched) is called intentionally to yield, among others.

Comment: I see. Still this "-race" utility has to provide some warning in case of the situation described. The end user might be unaware about the value of GOMAXPROCS. After all, the fact that the program ocassionally yields outputs other that 1000 is nothing else but a 100% race condition

Comment: @mangusta: the race detector only detects data races, and this is absolutely not a data race. You could consider it a "logical" race of sorts, but the program is executing exactly as it was intended. In fact even `1` is valid output here, if the goroutines all yield at the same point between the load and store.